# java web service for POST method

Tags: java

Can someone post simple code for java rest web service to add two parameters with "POST" method.I know how to work with "GET" method.But facing difficulty with "POST" method.Also provide client part to invoke web service.Please do help.

Comment: This is no please-write-me-my-code site... Please try by yourself and if you then encounter a specific problem or error message you are right to ask for a solution at stack overflow. Please also refer to the FAQ and read "How to ask" and the various other articles.

Comment: Also I'm sure you're not the first person on this world to encounter this "problem". Please do a bit of research at the various search engines out there. I'm almost 100% sure, that there are existing resources to help you.

Comment: I tried everything but could not able to solve my problem.So finally i end up asking here

Comment: You'll find some examples here http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/ (Jersey assumed)

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried? This feels a little like you're asking us to do your homework. Especially when the answers you want can be Googled in seconds and there are many tutorials available that cover this.

Comment: please share a code of what you have tried, we can correct / suggest the same.